# Getting error when using variable_width_histogram aggregation 'Too many buckets'

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, elasticsearch-aggregation

We are trying to execute a query to get variable_width_histogram aggregation results but getting an error 'Trying to create too many buckets'. However bucket size in query is 10. When trying to get bucket size 8, I am able to get results correctly but with size 10, this error is coming.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "fields": [
                    "field1",
                    "field2"
                  ],
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "query": "(product1)"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "minMaxPriceRangeData": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": []
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "piceRangeData": {
          "variable_width_histogram": {
            "field": "value",
            "buckets": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Total result doc count are 7974263 on which this query is running. Is there any other way we can extract similar data without any error?

Tried by passing less number of buckets and in that case getting results correctly.

I don't want to change my cluster settings for this. Instead looking for getting results from query itself.

Comment: You can increase it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html#search-settings-max-buckets

Comment: We don't want to change elastic cluster setting for this. any other way around ?

Comment: Can you give an idea of the distribution of the values in the `value` field? What's the type and range of those field values?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: data type of value field is 'double'. In current results it is coming 158442862 and even more high values depending upload documents.

Comment: Getting error - 
```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "",
    "phase": "fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "too_many_buckets_exception",
      "reason": "Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [65536] but this number of buckets was exceeded. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting.",
      "max_buckets": 65536
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```